# Activity Indicator within UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, uiactivityindicatorview

I've read a few answers about this particular topic, but for some reason, my code doesn't seem to work. It's within the UISearchBarDelegate delegate method `-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar`

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
UIBarButtonItem *activity = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:activityIndicator];
[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:activity];
[activity release];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: You might be missing activityIndicatorViewStyle..! Also dont forget to release activityIndicator

Comment: Don't know if it is your situation, in one of my app, I make a little delay for the indicator to come up using for example: 
[self performSelector:@selector(yourmethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];

Answer (score 2):

I believe the designated initializer for `UIActivityIndicatorView` is `initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:`. Try creating `activityIndicator` like this.

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
```

Comment: No luck, unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion though. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure the delegate method is being called?

Comment: Definitely. Everything else is happening correctly (including the other things within the delegate method).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
UIView *view_actviti = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6,310,59,32)];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *act =[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];
    act.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
    UIBarButtonItem *actItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:view_actviti] autorelease];
    [view_actviti addSubview:act];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = actItem;
    [act startAnimating];
```

Comment: No luck here either. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = 
    [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
UIBarButtonItem * barButton = 
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:activityIndicator];

[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:barButton];

[barButton release];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

Also use this for stopping and removing activityIndicator:

```
[[self navigationItem] setLRightBarButtonItem:nil];
[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
[activityIndicator release];
```